# Innocent-looking Diophantine equation with smallest solution of the order $10^{50}$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Recently someone mentioned to me that there is a diophantine equation that looks very simple and innocent, but the smallest solution involves numbers of the order $10^{50}$ or something like this. The equation is probably in either 1,2, or 3 varaibles. It has low coefficients, probably all 1 or 2. And the degree is low also, probably 4 or less.

Is there such an equation?

Edit: I think the equation might have been studied by Fermat, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This would be what happens when people think there are no solutions at all. It is usually difficult to prove emptiness of a solution set in one paper, so people find partial results, often giving huge lower bounds on possible solutions. Other than that, we do not read minds.

Comment: The claim seems quite plausible to me. I do not have such an example off-hand but  the smallest solution of the "really simple"  $x^2 -109 y^2=1$ is  $(158070671986249,15140424455100)$.

Comment: Now I am remembering better and he said the coefficients were all $1$ or $2$. The equation you proposed is much more difficult than the one my friend described.

Comment: What would be relevant is the degree of the equation also.

Comment: Do $x^3+y^3+z^3=30$ counts? The smallest solution is $(2220422932,-2218888517,-283059965)$

Comment: Contact your friend. I do not see how it is our responsibility to guess what your friend meant, especially if he was not entirely clear on the details.

Comment: The smallest solution of the Pell equation $\ p^2-d q^2 \!= 1,\ \ d = 4\cdot 609\cdot 7766\cdot 4657^2 $ arising from the ancient [Archimedes Cattle Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_cattle_problem) has over  a **couple hundred thousand** decimal digits.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I've seen the Archimedes cattle problem but it is not at all suprising that the solution will be very large, because it is a system with 10 or so equations.

Comment: @Joshua The Archimedes cattle problem starts with seven tiny linear Diophantine equations and reduces to solving $\ x^2 - d y^2 = 1\ $ for $\ d = 410286423278424.\ $ You don't find it surprising that the smallest solution has $\,206544\,$ decimal digits?

Comment: But $d$ has 15 digits, so it's concievable that the solution will be very large, especially with 7 contraints to satisfy. I suppose $20,6544$ is a bit suprising. But the equation we are looking for is even simpler than the Archimedes problem.

Comment: @Joshua The Pell equation is the only constraint (btw, I mxed up the two parts of the problem above, see the linked article for details;  esp. Lenstra's exposition). In any case, I thought you would find it of interest.

Comment: Well it is interesting that pell equations can give very large solutions relative to $d$.

Comment: The most famous versions of Pell´s equation is the above mentioned  Archimedes cattle problem and the case d=61 with x=1 766 319 049,  y= 226 153 980.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The smallest (in terms of naive height) solution of $y^2=x^3+877x$ is

$$\left(\frac{375494528127162193105504069942092792346201}{6215987776871505425463220780697238044100},\frac{256256267988926809388776834045513089648669153204356603464786949}{490078023219787588959802933995928925096061616470779979261000}\right)$$

This is an example of Bremner and Cassels. Thus, the smallest solution of $ZY^2=X^3+877XZ^2$ is
$$(29604565304828237474403861024284371796799791624792913256602210,256256267988926809388776834045513089648669153204356603464786949,490078023219787588959802933995928925096061616470779979261000).$$
The $X$ coordinate is $>2\cdot 10^{61}$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a general comment about the mechanism behind this phenomenon. By [Matiyasevich's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_set#Matiyasevich.27s_theorem), the problem of determining whether a Diophantine equation has a solution is undecidable. This implies that it is not possible to give a computable *a priori* bound on the size of the solutions to a Diophantine equation (since, given such a bound, we could solve Diophantine equations by checking all solutions up to the bound), so it follows that the size of the smallest solution to a Diophantine equation eventually exceeds any computable function of the Diophantine equation.

Comment: For small degrees and symmetric equations is always possible to write a formula for solving equations.  Everything solved quadratic forms.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a ***monster***. The smallest integer solution to,

$$(x + a)^7 + (x - a)^7 + (2x + b)^7 + (2x - b)^7 + \\(-x - c)^7 + (-x + 
        c)^7 + (-2x - d)^7 + (-2x + d)^7 \\= 14^7(a^6 + 2b^6 - c^6 - 2d^6)^7$$

has $x$ with $\color{red}{1179\; \text{digits}}$. The variables $a,b,c,d$ are,

$$292565171139318137956759657471297,\\ 863420822620431936290192229011966,\\ 
534407060429869176086407612538177,\\ 859793943610761912321826231621886$$

and

$$\small{x =481563304865430516682423843723465575123177045754683810551700\dots \approx \color{red}{4.81 \times 10^{1178}}}$$

Ajai Choudhry found this using an elliptic curve, which may explain the large values.